# How do I POST an array with x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: api

I tried "x-www-form-urlencoded" POST request with tags,
it was showing an error "has to be an array"

please guide me this endpoint what is required in this value field.

Screenshot attached.[image]

Answer (score 2):

To send param `tags` as an array, include the key `tags` more than once with each value on a separate line.

[image]

You should use the same key for each element in your array. If you have just one element in your array, as in your example, leave the second value for `tags` empty and handle empty values in your endpoint function.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have `tags` and `["transactions"]` in the postman screenshot. Use `tags[]` and `transactions` instead.